# MYSQL How to compare price from two tables and show all results

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have two tables feed_new and feed_old where both have id,name,price. When ever user go to price check will be able to see whole list with products and then to see the different(price change, product deleted/missing, stock change) between them

I make a query to pull the differents between old and new feed but i need to show and rest of the records in one query not only differents , how to do it ?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT fo.id, fo.name,fo.price,fo.product_code, fo.stock, fn.id AS id_new, fn.name AS name_new, fn.price AS price_new, fn.product_code AS product_code_new, fn.stock AS stock_new 
FROM feed_old fo 
LEFT JOIN feed_new fn ON (fn.product_code = fo.product_code) 
WHERE fo.price <> fn.price OR fn.product_code IS NULL ");
```

and this will result:

```
id      name       price    product_code    stock   id_new  name_new    price_new   product_code_new    stock_new   
4659    Product     481     9997454          29     NULL       NULL     NULL        NULL                 NULL
4665    Product1    326     9997460          0      4665    Product1    3260        9997460              0
4666    Product2    324     9997461          2      4666    Product2    3240        9997461              2
4644    Product3    217     9998929          42     NULL       NULL     NULL        NULL                 NULL
```

then i can loop the results like this one

```
<table class="table">
<?php foreach ($query as $product): ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $product['name'] ?> </td>
    <td> 
      <?php echo $product['price'] ?> 
      <?php if ($product['price_new'] != ''): ?>
          <?php if $product['price'] <> $product['price_new']): ?>
            <?php echo "New price" ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php elseif($product['price_new'] == '') ?>
        <?php echo "Product deleted" ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: i saw it and still do not understand what is the problem @Strawberry

Comment: Then you're in good company

Comment: Collect product codes from both tables (UNION) in subquery, then join both tables to it. `product_code` must be unique over each table (if not then your current query is not clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, there is no need of using fo.price <> fn.price condition in you query

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT fo.id, fo.name,fo.price,fo.product_code, fo.stock, 
fn.id AS id_new, fn.name AS name_new, fn.price AS price_new, fn.product_code AS 
product_code_new, fn.stock AS stock_new 
FROM feed_old fo 
LEFT JOIN feed_new fn ON (fn.product_code = fo.product_code)
```

this query will get every old feed with(or without) related new feed